# react-hook-form Limiting Length and Type using Material UI Text Field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, maxlength, react-hook-form

Given the code below, I am unable to limit the number of digits a user can enter into a text field and control the type of input.

**If** I remove `type: "number"` then the input length **can** be controlled but letters can now be entered.

**If** I remove `maxLength: 4` then the input length **can't** be controlled but letters are no longer allowed.

**If** I set `inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, type: "number" }}` as seen below, only the `type: "number"` input constraint is being enforced.

What can I do to fix this?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch"
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        inputProps={{ maxLength: 4, type: "number" }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maxlength doesn't apply to number inputs, you need to use a combination of min and max values.

A user can still input values above the max number but the validation will show as an error. And if they use the spinners, that'll be the max value it'll go to.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>text - maxlength=4 <input maxlength="4" /></label>

<label>number - maxlength=4 <input type="number" maxlength="4" /></label>

<label>number - max=999&amp;min=-999 <input type="number" max="999" min="-999" /></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the type=numeric and added some regx. Note I am using Controller not Register.

```
<Controller
        rules={{ required: required }}
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <TextField
            {...field}
            onKeyDown={numericOnly}
            inputProps={{ inputMode: "numeric", pattern: pattern ?? "[0-9]*", maxLength:maxLength }}
          />
        )}
      />
```

```
  const numericOnly = (e) => {
    if (
      !/[0-9]/.test(e.key) &&
      e.key !== "Backspace" &&
      e.key !== "Delete" &&
      e.key !== "Enter"
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```